# How can I sort an ArrayList of Strings in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have `String`s that are put into an `ArrayList` randomly.

```
private ArrayList<String> teamsName = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] helper;
```

For example:

```
teamsName.add(helper[0]) where helper[0] = "dragon";   
teamsName.add(helper[1]) where helper[1] = "zebra";   
teamsName.add(helper[2]) where helper[2] = "tigers" // and so forth up to about 150 strings.
```

Given the fact that you cannot control the inputs (i.e. string that is coming into the ArrayList is random; zebra or dragon in any order), once the ArrayListis filled with inputs, how do I sort them alphabetically excluding the first one?

`teamsName[0]` is fine; sort `teamsName[1 to teamsName.size]` alphabetically.

Comment: Use Collections.sort() with subList()

Comment: and btw why is first element excluded ? I hope it's not because first element is the header element like 'Team name'... that should be managed in frontend only, and filtered later...

Comment: first element is the name of my team so I would like to have that as first; it will be on the drop down menu so like how we have United States as the first and alphabetize the rest of the countries

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(teamsName.subList(1, teamsName.size()));
```

The code above will reflect the **actual sublist** of your original list sorted.

Comment: You need to delcare the sublist outside the sort to get the results: ``List<String> sublist = teamsName.subList(1, teamsName.size()); Collections.sort(sublist);``

Comment: Shouldn't the `fromIndex` in the subList be a 0 instead of a 1?

Comment: @dokaspar No. The OP expressly wants to exclude the first element.  Read the question - specifically at the end.

Comment: OP's request can create some misunderstanding when copying and pasting.. As question looks more generic...

Answer (score 12):

Check [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method. This automatically sorts your list according to natural ordering. You can apply this method on each sublist you obtain using [`List#subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method.

```
private List<String> teamsName = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> subList = teamsName.subList(1, teamsName.size());
Collections.sort(subList);
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [`Collections.sort(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

You can simply remove the first element, sort the list and then add it back again.

Answer (score 5):

You might sort the `helper[]` array directly:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(helper, 1, helper.length);
```

Sorts the array from index 1 to the end. Leaves the first item at index 0 untouched.

See [Arrays.sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TreeSet` that automatically order list values:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Tree Set Example!\n");

        TreeSet <String>tree = new TreeSet<String>();
        tree.add("aaa");
        tree.add("acbbb");
        tree.add("aab");
        tree.add("c");
        tree.add("a");

        Iterator iterator;
        iterator = tree.iterator();

        System.out.print("Tree set data: ");

        //Displaying the Tree set data
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

I lastly add 'a' but last element must be 'c'.

Comment: `TreeSet` is definitely handy but a set is not a list. Using `TreeSet` will remove duplicates which may be unwanted: the question is about sorting, not sorting *and* de-duping.