# how to sort an arraylist that contains string arrays?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
List<String[]> allWordList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to sort the "allWordList" list based on the first element in string array alphabetically.

I have a list that contains string array which are of size 2. So basically i want to sort this list by comparing the first element of the string array.

```
Collection.sort();
```

does not work as it is used to sort......

```
List<String>
```

and not

```
List<String[]>
```

to be clear i do not want to sort the individual string[] elements. I would like to sort the entire list based on the very first element of the string array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting arraylist in alphabetical order (case insensitive)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive)

Comment: @Arrthur: Not a duplicate I have string[] inside a list whereas the other question has just strings

Answer (score 6):

A simple custom comparator should do the trick.

The only tricky thing is making sure that you are not indexing into an empty array:

```
Collections.sort(allWordList, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        if (o1.length == 0) {
            return o2.length == 0 ? 0 : -1;
        }
        if (o2.length == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return o2[0].compareTo(o1[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: does not work says the first argument is wrong>>Found : List<String[]>, Required: String[][]

Comment: @vivekverma You are right, this should be `Collections.sort`. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you checking the array size and tolerate empty arrays? The arrays should have a size of 2.

Comment: *"sort this list by comparing the **first element** of the string array"*. Without further description, it is an error for the array to be `null` or empty, same as it is an error for the first element to be `null`. Both `null` and empty means "missing" and *should fail!* If you want to invent sorting rule for missing element (empty array), you might as well invent sorting rules for null too.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your own comparator, for example as a lambda expression:

```
allWordList.sort((o1, o2) -> o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]));
```

Comment: Since values are string arrays, maybe `s1` (for "string") or `a1` (for "array") is better than `o1` (for "object").

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a variation of @dasblinkenlight 's answer where I'd don't think comparing array length's is correct behavior.

```
private void sort() {
    List<String[]> allWordList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    // fill the list...
    Collections.sort(allWordList, new FirstElementComparator());
    // and so on...
}

private static class FirstElementComparator implements Comparator<String[]>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] sa1, String[] sa2) {
        String str1 = sa1[0];
        String str2 = sa2[0];

        int result = 0;
        if (str1 == null) {
            result = (str2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
        }
        else {
            result = str1.compareTo(str2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
allWordList
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a[0], String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can omit the [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) if the ordering should be case-sensitive.

Or if you need locale-dependent ordering, take a look at [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

Answer (score -3):

Check This :

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive)

Option 2 :

```
Collections.sort(teamsName.subList(1, teamsName.size()));
```

Source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046532/how-can-i-sort-an-arraylist-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: You realize OP has a String _array_?